# Road Intersection mesh generation

Tags: unity, mesh

For the last month I was learning about meshes and how procedurally generate them. For what I need it looks very straightforward.
For my little app I planning to have a road tool (very simple), user draws lines and curves and road is generated with specific width (flat).
So I can now create a drawing tool and generate simple mesh along the curve or line.
Next step is to be able to construct intersections...

I looked at lots of example but couldn't find any descriptions how it is done.

1. Could you please advice what approach to take, how to identify intersection of two or multiple curves and generate mesh junction?
2. Also could you please advice on bigger picture, should I have sort of underline system for city building app, like graph, to know where to place road intersections, buildings and so on?

Thank you

This is a quick prototype I did (not in code)
https://youtu.be/1TxxB-ofLAo

Comment: Part 2 of your question is asking for information on creating a city simulation. Are you just trying to create an illustration tool? Or a city simulation where the roads must make sense?

Comment: Trying to create a city simulation. So yes, roads have to make sense. At this stage I want to understand how to approach the creation of road system and mesh creation for intersections?